# Fabric/Crashlytics incompatible swift versions

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics

I've downloaded and updated to the latest Fabirc/Crashlytics release, but now I'm getting the following error:

```
error: The following binaries use incompatible versions of Swift:
/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-abcdefghijk/Build/Products/SomeScheme-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/blah/blah
/Users/me/iOS/my-project-ios/Dependencies/Fabric.framework/upload-symbols
```

You can check the change log where the latest release (Fabric 1.10.0, Crashlytics 3.13.0, May 10) combines the pervious `uploadDSYM` executable with `upload-symbols`, which is the one causing the issue.  https://docs.fabric.io/apple/changelog.html

I've tried all the typical solutions, cleaning, deleting derived data, restarting Xcode, etc.

The project runs in Swift 4.2

Any ideas?

Comment: I am also getting this issue, my project uses Swift 5 and Crashlytics version 3.13.0.  This problem started right after I updated to the latest version of Crashlytics.  Cleaning and deleting derived data did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I received this official response from Fabric support:

Thank you for reaching out to us and sorry that you are running into this issue, We are aware of this and are actively working on a fix! The following work around should unblock you till then:

There seems to be an issue impacting manual downloads (Latest SDKs) and Xcode 10.2. This is a bug with Xcode checking binaries for Swift versions, even when the binaries aren't actually bundled with the app.

In the meantime, to unblock these customers, have them:

1) Go into "Build Phases"

2) Remove Fabric.framework and Crashlytics.framework

For both Crashlytics and Fabric:

3) Click the + and then "Add Other..." in the lower left corner

4) Navigate to the .framework folder, and instead of selecting the .framework, select the "Crashlytics" and "Fabric" binaries themselves (they're at the top level of the framework)

Make you you do not still have Fabric.framework or Crashlytics.framework in your project.

Comment: Problem is that deleting those makes integration not work right, as ... it will no longer upload symbols (the older uploadDSYM files are no longer being invoked).

However, either that or going back to previous version is required to build successfully right now...

Comment: @siegfoult This worked for me.  If you remove the suggestion to delete the upload-symbols files (it's not a particularly acceptable solution in probably many cases) I'll accept the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update to 1.10.1 that was released today (May 16), it fixes the issue.

Comment: I have this problem with v 2

Comment: Latest version of Fabric as of March 10 2020 is `1.10.2`. If you're using Crashlytics, you cannot simply update Fabric pod with `pod update Fabric`, because Fabric and Crashlytics have a circular dependency to each other. First remove Crashlytics from your Podfile, update Fabric, then install the latest version of Crashlytics.

Answer (score -1):

Please Note that Fabric and Crashlytics are **going to shutdown** soon in Year 2020 by google. So kindly migrate your project(s) from Fabric to Firebase.

Refer:

https://get.fabric.io/roadmap

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-from-crash-reporting